# 'Piling' an Array, Collapse by Summation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sum, bin

Given a numpy array, I'd like to sum up uniform chunks of elements to form a new, smaller, array. It's similar to binning, but not by frequency. I'm not sure how else to describe it other than by example (below).

**The question**: Is there either a function for this or cleaner approach (using numpy/scipy)? I've looked into `digitize` and `histogram`, but think their implementations are lengthy. I've also thought about crafty indexing, but it's beyond me and might make a long ugly line of code.

```
import numpy as np  

old_data = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
bin_size = 3
new_data = np.zeros(int(np.size(old_data) / bin_size))
for ind, val in enumerate(new_data):
    leap = ind*bin_size
    new_data[ind] = 
np.sum(old_data[leap:leap+bin_size])
print(old_data, '->', bin_size, ':', new_data)

# [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8] -> 3 : [ 3. 12. 21.]
```

Comment: maybe `np.array([sum(old_data[bin_size*i: bin_size*(i+1)]) for i in range(old_data.size // bin_size)])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there's an integral number of bins, you can accomplish this with a reshape:

```
old_data = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
bin_size = 3

new_data = old_data.reshape(-1, bin_size).sum(axis=1)
```

`new_data` will then have the desired value of:

```
array([ 3, 12, 21])
```

If `bin_size` doesn't divide evenly into `old_data.size`, you can instead use `resize`:

```
old_data = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
bin_size = 3

old_data.resize(old_data.size//bin_size + 1, bin_size)
new_data = old_data.sum(axis=1)
```

`new_data` will then have a value of:

```
array([ 3, 12, 21, 19])
```

Using `resize` has the downside of modifying `old_data` in place, so if you want to keep `old_data` around you should probably make a copy of it before you do the `resize`.

Comment: This is concise and does exactly as desired in a very legible manner. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a clean way to do this without altering the original array? One could simply `np.copy` it into a dummy array, but surely there's a slick way around this.